# Action of the centre on Hochschild cohomology

Tags: ring-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, hochschild-cohomology

Let $A$ be an associative algebra, $Z(A)$ the centre of $A$, $C^n(A, A) = \mbox{Hom}_{A^e}(A^{\otimes n +2}, A)$ the $n$-th component of the Hochschild cochain complex, $b:C^n(A,A) \to C^{n+1}(A, A)$ the Hochschild coboundary map and $HH^n(A)$ the $n$-th Hochschild cohomology of $A$ (with coefficients in $A$). Define the action of $Z(A)$ on $C^n(A, A)$ by

$$(a\cdot f)(a_1\otimes \dots\otimes a_{n+2}) = af(a_1\otimes \dots\otimes a_{n+2}) $$

For $a\in Z(A)$ and $f\in C^n(A,A)$. Now, I'm reading *Hochschild Cohomology for Algebras* by Sarah Witherspoon, and in the section that discusses this action she writes

> this action commutes with the differentials on the bar complex,
> inducing an action of $Z(A)$ on $HH^n(A)$ under which $HH^n(A)$ becomes a
> $Z(A)$-module.

(I'm assuming that the use of the term "bar complex" here is just for ease since $C^*(A, A)$ is technically the cochain complex you get after applying the functor $\mbox{Hom}_{A^e}(-, A)$ to the bar complex, rather than the bar complex itself.)

My question is, why does the fact that this action commutes with $b$ mean that it induces an action of $Z(A)$ on $HH^n(A)$?

My initial thoughts about this is that since $a\in Z(A)$ then

$$af(a_1\otimes \dots\otimes a_{n+2}) = f(a_1\otimes \dots\otimes a_{n+2})a$$

and since it also commutes with the differential then $a\cdot [f] := [af] = [fa]$. But if $a$ already commutes with $f$ then doesn't that automatically make the equivalence classes $[af]$ and $[fa]$ the same, regardless of whether $a$ commutes with $b$? So why is this commutativity with $b$ necessary? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out where my confusion was coming from.

First off I misunderstood the term "commutes" in this context. It's referring to the fact that

$$(a\cdot b(f))(a_1\otimes\dots\otimes a_{n+2}) = b(a\cdot f)(a_1\otimes\dots\otimes a_{n+2})$$

Therefore, if we have $[f] = [g] \in HH^n(A)$, then this implies that there is some map $h$ such that

$$f - g = b(h)$$

and so applying our action to this expression we get

$$a\cdot f - a\cdot g = a\cdot (f- g) = a\cdot b(h) = b(a\cdot h) $$

and therefore $[a\cdot f] = [a\cdot g]$. So the commutativity of the action with the differential means that the action

$$a\cdot [f] = [a\cdot f] $$

of $Z(A)$ on $HH^n(A)$ is well defined. And then showing that $HH^n(A)$ is a $Z(A)$-module is an easy exercise of checking the definition.